# Stored procedure in Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use a stored procedure with join in Entity Framework Core 5. I have created the stored procedure using code-first migration.

How can I retrieve data from non-entity type that the stored procedure returns, and then display in view?

Comment: Please have a look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/54154.entity-framework-core-5-stored-procedures-net-5-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<output>>> Getoutput(Input input)
    {
        string StoredProc = "exec YourStoreProcedure " +
                "@Id= '" + input.Id+ "'";

        return await _context.output.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync();
    }
```